# Why Attribute Saving via Admin Side Changes Backend Type to INT

Tags: admin, attributes, magento-1, backend, select

I saw a serious issue with Select type attributes in Magento.

If backend model of a select attribute is other than `INT` (for example : `varchar`, `text`) etc. then if we edit this attribute via admin side and save, then it's backend type will be changed to `INT`

This is a serious issue because this will leads to indexing issues, product disappears from categories and search and abnormal sorting issues.

**Why Magento behaves like this? How can we overcome this ?**

As of now, It seems that, it is better to create [All select attribute with a backend model `INT`](http://www.jalpanam.com/magento/beware-keep-all-of-your-select-attributes-as-int-in-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, we need to stick on `INT` type whenever we want to create a select attributes. Reasons are **[well described in my own blog](http://www.jalpanam.com/magento/beware-keep-all-of-your-select-attributes-as-int-in-magento/)**

Main points are:

> - Suppose you have a select attribute which backend type is `varchar`. Everything is fine. You can assign this attribute to an attribute set
>     and all products are saving all it’s values as we need. Now you came
>     to a situation in which you want to update this attribute via backend.
>     Of course, you can do this via admin side, `Catalog > Attributes >
>     Manage Attributes > [Select Your Attribute] > [Do all changes] >
>     SAVE`. Bingo attribute is updated, but if you check your database an
>     important hack is done without your knowledge which is backend type of
>     your attribute is now `INT` and not `VARCHAR`. This is definitely
>     going to make problems in future. Why Magento changes backend type of
>     attribute while save via backend. I really don’t know and I feel it’s
>     as serious bug.
> - Suppose you have a configurable product attribute which backend type is `varchar`. You did a massive product import to your system. Now
>     configurable product won’t show in category and even in search page.
>     There is no problem with other simple products which uses same
>     attribute, but configurable product won’t show in the assigned
>     category pages. I don’t know the real reason behind this. But most
>     probably this is an indexing issue. Instead if all of your
>     configurable attributes are using backend type as `INT`, then there is
>     no problem at all.